# "Bug" in today's update?

Tags: upgrade, updates

Today's Ubuntu 16.04 LTS update seems to contain a bug. When I use the Calculator and then type in an e-mail, it doesn't work, and instead types in the Calculator's results window. I've tried this a number of times and the results are identical.

This is something I do virtually every day (calculate in the Calculator, then type in an e-mail), but the Calculator no longer allows me to type anywhere but in the Calculator. I must completely exit the Calculator to type in another document.

Comment: not for me. Please be more specific what you're exactly doing... which Email program, etc...

Comment: I was as specific as I could be. When Calculator is open, I cannot type in an e-mail, ONLY in the Calculator that comes with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. This began happening after the 20 June update, NOT before.